# Accessing unnamed list elements inside base::with()

Tags: r, list, with-statement

My question is whether this is possible. Given a list

```
lst <- list(a = 1, 2)
```

One can put `with(lst, a)` to return the first element.  But can you return the second element using `with` without first naming it?

Doesn't work:

```
with(lst, [[2]])
with(lst, `2`)
with(lst, ..2)
```

I suspect that this is not possible because `with(lst, ls(all.names = TRUE))` gives just `"a"`.  But does anyone know different?

I realise why `with(lst, 2)` could never work. And of course `[[` is a function, so it is clear that my first attempt would confuse R. However, it would be feasible that `with` would give special names to unnamed arguments so that they were accessible without having to re-access the list separately. For example, the second element could be called `..2` in the environment set up by `with`. This is not the case, though.

In this example one would simply use `lst[[2]]`.  But I am thinking in terms of a complex expression for a large multi-levelled list, for which some elements are named and others not.  The code would be much more readable using a `with` statement to start at a convenient level of subsetting.  But having some needed elements unnamed is a barrier for this.

Comment: Well yes, in this trivial case.  The context when this is useful is if you are deep inside a multi-levelled list using a a complex expression with some named and some unnamed elements.  The idea is to reduce the amount of text required in the code.

Comment: @akrun I have provided the simplest reproducible example.  As always with coding, the simplest example does not show why we bother with complex code, but demonstrates a principle which can be applied to more complex code.

Comment: The answer to the simplest problems is generally not to bother with code and get out the abacus.

Comment: `with` moves the evaluation inside its "data" argument. While an "a" inside `lst` is different from an "a" in -say- `.GlobalEnv`, the number "2" is the same in both. Also, if you wanted to add the actual number "2" to the second element of `lst`, what should `with(lst, 2 + 2)` (a corresponding to `with(lst, a + 2)`) understand..?

Comment: I realise why `with(lst, 2)` could never work.  And of course `[[` is a function, so it is clear that my first attempt would confuse R.  However, it would be feasible that `with` would give special names to unnamed arguments so that they were accessible without having to re-access the list separately.  For example, the second element could be called `..2` in the environment set up by `with`.  This is not the case, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible. You can't reference an unnamed object from within a list.

```
lst <- list(a = 1, 2)
```

This is what `with` does:

```
eval(substitute(a), lst, enclos = parent.frame())
#[1] 1
```

The only object accessible from within `lst` is `a`:

```
eval(substitute(ls()), lst, enclos = parent.frame())
#[1] "a"
```

I'd suggest naming all components of the list. (And to be honest, I don't really see a common use case.)